# Running a file whose handle is opened(C++ winapi)

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess, createfile

I included a exe file as a resource in my c++ application and i need to run it, but i need to restrict it's access alot so the user can't copy it.
I need to keep it's handle opened so external programs can't access it, and because i used FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE as a flag, so it will delete if my application gets killed.

But because of that i can't run it with CreateProcess() or WinExec().
I know it sounds weird, but i have a good reason.I need those to protect the executable of a game from a dll-injection cheat, and i don't have the code of that exe.

Comment: There's no fool proof way of keeping users from copying your executable... just sayin'

Comment: I know, but the actual difficulty of copying that file is enough for me.

Comment: There are so many holes in this strategy, you should re-consider. You can just shut the computer off while it's running, restart, and your file won't be deleted. Any novice user could do that. Also, if it's included as a resource it can just be extracted. How about designing your app so it doesn't matter if people copy the .exe?

Comment: problem:I can't modify the exe I want to protect, it's not mine and I don't have the source, it will still bug the majority of cheaters.
That is not the problem though, i can't run the exe because i need to keep it's file handle opened.

Comment: How does preventing users from copying the file prevent a DLL injection?

Comment: Well my program will run the game exe and constantly check it from dll injection.But the game exe can run without my program and it's vulnerable.By copying it they can run the game without my protection.
But this is not the point of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't lock the entire file, lock a very small part with `LockFile`. You'll need to find a byte range that Windows doesn't use. You might achieve this by adding a dummy resource to the EXE. (This does not require source code).